# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: permission denied for table

Tags: node.js, express, node-postgres

I'm building a node express web application that interfaces with a postgres database using `node-pg`. In my local environment everything runs fine but when I pull the project from github on a different machine and try to run it I get the following error:
`(node:445) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: permission denied for table <some table>`

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error as I am connecting to the same database with the same credentials as from the local environment, and I've tried to make sure the proper privileges are granted by using the command `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLE <some table> TO postgres;` and then restarting the database service.

Is there something I'm missing or how would I go about solving this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I can't suggest an overall fix for your connection issues we can fix the `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` by literally handling the Promise rejection.

```
try {
  // connect to pg
}
catch(e) {
  console.error(e)
  // Probably if you can't connect to the DB at all that's an unrecoverable problem.
  // I'd log whatever useful stats about the running application as you can and then maybe just end the process.
  process.exit(1)
}
```

[Note the docs for process.exit()](https://nodejs.dev/learn/how-to-exit-from-a-nodejs-program) though, that "This means that any callback that's pending, any network request still being sent, any filesystem access, or processes writing to stdout or stderr - all is going to be ungracefully terminated right away." which may or may not be a problem for you.

Comment: Awesome thank you, the problem ended up being an issue with user permissions on the postgres database

Comment: np :) glad you solved it.